# Is it possible to change the font size of the section number and text with fancyhdr

Tags: sectioning, fancyhdr, titlesec

We would like to change the font size of the section only, but as header and footer is set with fancyhdr, then we would like to use same package or a package that is not in conflict with fancyhdr. Our section and sub section looks like the following:

[image]

We would like it to look like the following:

[image]

Above is achieved with the titlesec package, but unfortunately that is in conflict with fancyhdr, and everything we have made with fancyhdr messes up whenever we try to use titlesec. Therefore, it is highly preferred to change the section font size in fancyhdr, as we do not wish to convert all the things we have written with fancyhdr to titlesec.

```
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\LARGE}{\hspace{1ex}\Huge\thesection}{2ex}{}
```

Following is the main file:

```
\documentclass[11pt, report]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec} % <------ changed
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lastpage,refcount,atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Header}   % Title
\author {Ahmad Ahmadsen} % Author
\date{\today} % Date

\makeatletter
\let\thetitle\@title
\let\theauthor\@author
\let\thedate\@date
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
\lhead{\thetitle} 

\rfoot{\thepage \space} 
\lfoot{University} 

\begin{document}

\cfoot{\thepage \space of \pageref{LastPage}}
\rfoot{} 
\lfoot{} 

\renewcommand \thesection{\arabic{section}}

% Add sections here!
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Motivation}
\subsection{Research Question}

\section{Analysis}
\subsection{analys 1}
\subsection{analys 2}
\subsection{analys 3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. Your problem is real because `fancyhdr` and `titlesec` are known to not play well with each other. There might be a way to get the sections to perform as you need. What we need to help you with that is a Minimal Working Example. That would be a MINIMAL whole file from `\documentclass{` to `\end{document}`. The main document you have posted is very long and contains a lot of unneeded information, as well as requires files we do not have.

Comment: @EladDen Yes, you are definitely right. I have changed it now, so now it is easier to copy over :-)

Comment: Why don't you use `titleps` with `titlesec`?

Comment: The conflict is not between `titlesec` and `fancyhdr`, but between `titleps` and `fancyhdr`, because they both define incompatible versions of `headrule` and `footrule`. `titleps` is loaded when you gave the `pagestyles` option to `titlesec`, but it doesn't make sense to have both `titleps` and `fancyhdr` in your document. If you use `fancyhdr`, don't use the `pagestyles` option of `titlesec` and there shouldn't be any conflict no matter what order they are loaded.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum Exactly! This is why i want a fancyhdr only solution. so far, my solution is only bound on fancyhdr, as can be seen on my MWE, and therefore i also need a solution using fancyhdr and not titlesec or titleps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`titlesec` uses macros that `fancyhdr` is also using. This is why if you put `\usepackage{titlesec}` after `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` you get errors. `\usepackage{titlesec}` to before `\usepackage{fancyhdr}`.

Also as @Buster3650 noted, `titlesec` defines `\thetitle` so it would be best to define a different name to be used in the header.

If you want ALL your sections to be the same, here is is in your MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, report]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec} % <------ This here 
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\LARGE}{\hspace{1ex}\Huge\thesection}{2ex}{} %<--- and this

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %<---- Before that there
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lastpage,refcount,atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Header}   % Title
\author {Ahmad Ahmadsen} % Author
\date{\today} % Date

\makeatletter
\let\mytitle\@title %<--- changed
\let\theauthor\@author
\let\thedate\@date
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
\lhead{\mytitle} %<--- changed

\rfoot{\thepage \space} 
\lfoot{University} 

\begin{document}

\cfoot{\thepage \space of \pageref{LastPage}}
\rfoot{} 
\lfoot{} 

\renewcommand \thesection{\arabic{section}}

% Add sections here!
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Motivation}
\subsection{Research Question}

\section{Analysis}
\subsection{analys 1}
\subsection{analys 2}
\subsection{analys 3}

\end{document}
```

This also works if you want to start with this format at a certain point

```
\documentclass[11pt, report]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec} % <------ This

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % <---- Before That
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lastpage,refcount,atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Header}   % Title
\author {Ahmad Ahmadsen} % Author
\date{\today} % Date

\makeatletter
\let\mytitle\@title %<--- changed
\let\theauthor\@author
\let\thedate\@date
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
\lhead{\mytitle} %<--- changed

\rfoot{\thepage \space} 
\lfoot{University} 

\begin{document}

\cfoot{\thepage \space of \pageref{LastPage}}
\rfoot{} 
\lfoot{} 

\renewcommand \thesection{\arabic{section}}

% Add sections here!
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Motivation}
\subsection{Research Question}

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\LARGE}{\hspace{1ex}\Huge\thesection}{2ex}{} %<--- Now this works
\section{Analysis}
\subsection{analys 1}
\subsection{analys 2}
\subsection{analys 3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have already tried this, and unfortunately that doesn't work. Notice the header, it is changed to "2.3" instead of the initial header "Header"

Comment: `titlesec` also defines `\thetitle`. So replace `\thetitle` with e.g. `\mytitle` and it should work.

Comment: Works! Thank you very much, your help is very much appreciated

Comment: Edited the answer to accomodate @Buster3650 comment

Answer (score 0):

The conflict is not between `titlesec` and `fancyhdr`, but between `titleps` and `fancyhdr`, because they both define incompatible versions of `\headrule` and `\footrule`. `titleps` is loaded when you gave the `pagestyles` option to `titlesec`, but it doesn't make sense to have both `titleps` and `fancyhdr` in your document. If you use `fancyhdr`, don't use the `pagestyles` option of `titlesec` and there shouldn't be any conflict no matter what order they are loaded.

The second problem is the use of `\thetitle`, which is defined by `titlesec`. So you should use a different name for this. I propose to use some capital letters, e.g. `TheTitle`, because names with capital letters usually give fewer conflicts.

So here is a solution that works:

```
\documentclass[11pt, report]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{titlesec} % <------ changed
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\LARGE}{\hspace{1ex}\Huge\thesection}{2ex}{}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lastpage,refcount,atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Header}   % Title
\author {Ahmad Ahmadsen} % Author
\date{\today} % Date

\makeatletter
\let\TheTitle\@title
\let\TheAuthor\@author
\let\TheDate\@date
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
\lhead{\TheTitle} 

\rfoot{\thepage \space} 
\lfoot{University} 

\begin{document}

\cfoot{\thepage \space of \pageref{LastPage}}
\rfoot{} 
\lfoot{} 

\renewcommand \thesection{\arabic{section}}

% Add sections here!
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Motivation}
\subsection{Research Question}

\section{Analysis}
\subsection{analys 1}
\subsection{analys 2}
\subsection{analys 3}

\end{document}
```

[image]